# JS - accessing global variable issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Best described by example:

I have the following piece of code:

```
/* YIELDS ERROR
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', '.zeon-merchandise-measure', function () {
    dropdownCssClass : 'zeon-select2-dropdown',
    data: merchandise_measures
});
*/

// OK
$(".zeon-merchandise-measure").select2({
  dropdownCssClass : 'zeon-select2-dropdown',
  data: merchandise_measures
});
```

I can't undesrand what is wrong with scope. The second function works ok, while `DOMNodeInserted`-part cannot recognize `merchandise_measures`

Here's how `merchandise_measures is defined (html page being loaded)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            // A global variables
            merchandise_measures = {{ merchandise_measures_json|safe }};
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first one isn't valid syntax, never mind scoping issues.  It's a function callback that's running, as opposed to an object being passed as a parameter.

Comment: ^ and there's another error, `{{ merchandise_measures_json|safe }}` cannot be used as an object constructor, but block statement?

Comment: You're almost creating labels in the first example, but presenting the comma.

Answer (score 0):

First example has invalid syntax. You are passing a function and using it as an object. I don't know your whole code and what are you trying to achieve but this is more valid:

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', '.zeon-merchandise-measure', function () {
    var myObject = {    
        dropdownCssClass : 'zeon-select2-dropdown',
        data: merchandise_measures
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that the function would still work (valid syntax) anyway if there was no comma separating "LABELS", bcuz JavaScript has labels, and they're similiar when declaring object props.